# TYPO3 singleSelect required

Tags: typo3

This is my TCA field configuration

```
    'membership_type' => [
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => $ll . '/locallang_db.xlf:my_label.type',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'foreign_table' => 'sys_category',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND sys_category.parent=' . $membershipTypeParent . ' AND (sys_category.sys_language_uid = 0 OR sys_category.l10n_parent = 0) ORDER BY sys_category.sorting ASC',
            'items' => [
                [$llg . 'fe_users.groups.unkonwn', 0]
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I want this field to be required. I tried setting:

['config']['eval'] = 'required';
['config']['minitems'] = 1;

But none of them seem to do the job. I found also this old thread on typo3 forge which says it is not possible https://forge.typo3.org/issues/60247. I am using TYPO3 8 now.
"Eval does not exist for select fields. However, what you're missing is a field to choose a non-empty value.
I suggest you use a multi-select with two selects (similar to fe_group in pages) where you can only select one item)."

I would prefer to stay with single select instead of multi-select. Is that possible ?

Comment: I do not really understand your question.
With a `selectSingle` and without an empty option you cant leave thie field blank?! 
Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Yes, but that is not a case here. I do have empty option and I don't want to remove it. If it is removed - then some users might just choose default option instead of choose the right one consciously. I don't want any of the option to be selected by default.

Comment: `minitems` should do the trick. I have it running on a v8 TYPO3. Maybe cache or similar?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler Well, I checked it again and minitems works only with renderType = selectMultipleSideBySide and does not work with renderType selectSingle ... Can you post your configuration minitems & selectSingle here please?

Answer (score -1):

Eval does exist for select fields, there will be something incorrect in your configuration.
Here's an example I made which works

```
'exampleSelectSingle' => array(
    'label' =>'Select Single',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'eval' => 'required',
        'items' => array(
            ['Empty',''],
            ['Label 1','value1'],
            ['Label 2','value2']
        )
    ),
    'size' => 1,
    'minitems' => 1
)
```

This renders correctly with the first (empty) option selected, which triggers the validation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXbdC.png

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use? This seems not to work for me too. And also seems to me like minitems and size properties should be place inside config array? As example here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#multiselectfilteritems

Comment: I'm on version 8.7.10